# No power to garage door opener and garage lights

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener

One morning all the lights aa well as my garage door opener stopped working. Even including the outer lights directly in front of the garage.  But all the outlets ive  checked still work just fine. And no breakers are tripped. Any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the breaker(s)? Sometimes when they trip, the handle still looks like it's in the ON position.

Comment: The lights might be on their own circuit or get their from the outlets.  If from the outlets then probably a bad or loose connection from one of the outlets.  Turn off the power before checking.

Answer (score 2):

Symptoms indicate either a GFCI trip (possibly a deadfront since the garage door opener is involved) or a loose connection between working and non-working devices.

Comment: If this occurred immediately after a rain, water may have gotten into an outdoor outlet, causing the GFCI to trip.